# How to export Silverlight Pivot View to Excel?

Tags: c#, silverlight, excel, pivot, pivotviewer

How I can export the current view in Silverlight Pivot Viewer to Excel.

Comment: take a look at this video tutorial http://vimeo.com/14275312

Comment: Interesting question.  What do you want to export? The PivotViewer is a visual representation of data.  Excel is a datasheet.  I don't see how the two relate unless you want to export the cxml file as a Excel pivot table.

Comment: @Alison well on my current view of pivot there are pictures with information so now i want to export these pictures with information to Excel, we can say just like excel pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

you can look in my blog for a way to do it. i explain how it works, and have also a video.

http://ruimarinho.net/2010/08/export-data-from-silverlight-pivotviewer-to-wpf-or-excel/